# SQLite remove rows two column crossly equal

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-room

I'm developing an android chat app. I'm using Room (SQLite persistence library) for storing data.
I have two tables: Friends and Messages. I want to display the latest message for every conversation.

Friends table:

```
data class FriendsModel(
     @PrimaryKey
     @SerialName("friendID") var friendID: String,
     @SerialName("friendName") var friendName: String?,
     @SerialName("friendPublicKey") var friendPublicKey: String?,
     @SerialName("sharedSecretKey") var sharedSecretKey: String?
)
```

Messages table:

```
data class MessageModel(
     @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
     @SerialName("id") var _id: Int = 0,
     @SerialName("from") var from: String,
     @SerialName("to") var to :String,
     @SerialName("message") var message: String?,
     @SerialName("date") var date: String?
)
```

Fake data to give an example:

[image]

Notice User1 sends 3 messages to User2, as well as User2 sends 3 messages to User1. I want to get every latest message on every conversation. It doesn't matter who send the last message ('from' or 'to' fields)

Return should be something like this:

[image]

I tried to sort by date and group by both **from** and **to**. But It gives me last message sent by User1 to User2 and by User2 to User1 at the same time. I want to eliminate this case.

Comment: If You use sorting by date, remind that You use a String as date value. I suggest store `timemillis` as Long in Your db.

Comment: Yes, i will use millis in production. This is just a fake data